# Combining NSArrays

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsarray

I have 3 NSArrays with:

item: amount

```
A: 1
B: 2
C: 3

A: 2
E: 1
F: 6

C: 5
D: 1
F: 3
```

After "combining" these into one, I need:

```
A: 3
B: 2
C: 8
D: 1
E: 1
F: 9
```

Do I first combine all the arrays into one and then sum and remove the duplicates?

Comment: Why are you using arrays instead of `NSDictionary`s for key-value mappings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a NSArray you could try using a NSMutableDictionary where the key is inherent in the objects structure. That will allow you to iterate through each of your arrays of letters and counts then query for the value with the key, get the value and add to the value, then continue processing.

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [`NSCountedSet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCountedSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I'm not clear on the structure of the data in your arrays, but by assuming that your `B: 2` means that you have two B's in the array, then something like this would work:

```
NSCountedSet *set = [NSCountedSet setWithCapacity:[array1 count]+[array2 count]+[array3 count]];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array1];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array2];
[set addObjectsFromArray:array3];

// Test it out!
NSUInteger countForC = [set countForObject:objC];
// countForC == 8
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility would be to use:

- Use predicates to extract like sets of data (by item) into separate arrays. See [Collection predicates guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)
- Key Value Coding to sum the value field of each of the resulting arrays (by item). See [KVO collection operators](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE).
- Pop the results in whatever structure you like (NSArray or NSDictionary).

There may be performance considerations to explore. Alternatively, iterate the array, pulling out matching items in a separate NSDictionary (keyed on item) and summing as you go.

Comment: Presuming the example records aren't just key-value pairs and this is just a simplified illustration.